# RegEx that can select multiple number formats?

Tags: regex

I have put together a regex that can detect most of the number types I need but I'm currently experiencing two issues with it.

1. It is including trailing spaces after the numbers.
2. In line 1 it is counting 10 / 43.3 as a single number but it should be two numbers separated by ' / '. It is however properly handling the '43 1/3' in line 3. (aside from the trailing space).

   `(\d+\.\d+|\d+[\/\d. ]*|\d)`

http://regexr.com/3fn5r

Comment: 10/43.3 is similar to 1/3, so i dont see any issues with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this regex and let me know if it matches your criteria,

```
/(\d+.\d+\/\d+|\d+\.\d|\d+)/igm
```